# ASP.NET read JSON data into GridView

Tags: asp.net, json, gridview

I have some json text which i would like to use to populate a gridview. I can get        it working if i dont have the headers part of it in the json data but if i do i get an error. Can someone please help me, not sure where im going wrong

Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path '[0].headers'

```
ASP.NET CODE

public class Emails
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string delivered_at { get; set; }
    public string sender { get; set; }
    public string email_ts { get; set; }
    public string email_id { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public string process_status { get; set; }
    public string smtpcode { get; set; }
    public string recipient { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string headers { get; set; }
} 

List<Emails> myDeserializedObjList = (List<Emails>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResult, typeof(List<Emails>));
                gvRecords.DataSource = myDeserializedObjList;
                gvRecords.DataBind();






JSON VALUE

[
{
  "status": "ok", 
  "delivered_at": "2014-02-12T20:51:48.000059+00:00", 
  "sender": "abc@123.co.nz", 
  "headers": {
    "subject": "Test No 1"
  }, 
  "email_ts": "2014-02-12T20:51:46.219800+00:00", 
  "email_id": "1WDgmY-4gfM00-Hj", 
  "host": "mx1.webhost.co.nz [119.47.119.2]", 
  "process_status": "completed", 
  "smtpcode": 250, 
  "recipient": "bob@123.co.nz", 
  "response": "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 8022160F4F"
}, 
{
  "status": "hardbounce", 
  "delivered_at": "2014-02-12T20:55:32.000047+00:00", 
  "sender": "jim@123.co.nz", 
  "headers": {
    "subject": "Test No 1"
  }, 
  "email_ts": "2014-02-12T20:55:30.028400+00:00", 
  "email_id": "1WDgqA-4gfLik-2I", 
  "host": "mx1.webhost.co.nz [119.47.119.2]", 
  "process_status": "completed", 
  "smtpcode": 550, 
  "recipient": "womble@123.co.nz", 
  "response": "550 5.1.1 <womble@123.co.nz>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table"
}
```

]

Comment: String property is not suitable for holding objectish value `{"subject": "Test No 1"}`, consider changing it's type.

Comment: I am calling a webservice so i dont have access to change the format that i get. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes formatting your JSON data

First , You should use Angel Braces [ after the "header" property like that :

```
    "headers":[ {
"subject": "Test No 1"
    }],
```

Second : In your model class , you defined smtpcode as a string property while you passed it an int value inside your JSON data

```
    "smtpcode": 250
```

It should be :

```
    "smtpcode" : "250"
```

OR

```
    public int smtpcode {get;set;} and keep it the same in JSON
```

Comment: I am calling a webservice so i dont have access to change the format that i get. thanks for pointing out the smtpcode can be in int instead of string